# Android TabLayout -- tabs are collapsed left

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-tablayout

I have implemented a working TabLayout. Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="4dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/club_sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="#EEEEEE"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I then load it with 4 tabs. What happens then is that the tabs don't fill the screen in width, but they are "linearly" added from left, so that there is empty space at the right end of the tab bar.

I tried `tabMode="fixed"` but that causes the tab titles to be broken into two lines, eg:

```
CALEND
AR
```

Anybody had the same issue and solved it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `app:tabMode="fixed"` instead of scrollable.

**EDIT:- For changing text size in tab layout**

To fix size of text in tabs

```
<style name="MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
   <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

and

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
```

Comment: Thanks @Nishant, I tried that but then the tab titles are broken into two lines..